# How to pass apostrophies from text areas to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, textarea, apostrophe

I have a text area that users add notes too. On the next page I use the `$_POST[Comments]` to show what was typed. I have an edit button to go back and see what was typed and edit the notes but when I show the `$_POST[Comments]` it shows everything up to an apostrophe.

Example:

Originally typed: `Let's try this.`

When Editing: `Let`

Now when I pass it to the server to do an SQL add I use the following function to protect against SQL injection

```
function keepSafe($value) {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        if (!is_numeric($value)) {
            $value = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
        }
        return $value;
    }
```

The following is what I use to format the input for SQL insertion.

```
$Comments = str_replace("\n","<br />",$_POST['CustComments']);
    $Comments = keepSafe($_POST['Comments']);
```

I need to be able to see all of the apostrophes in the notes section when editing before submission. And I want to make sure that when I do submit it is a SQL injection prevented safe code.

Comment: You first use `$_POST['CustComments']` and then `$_POST['Comments']` in your last example, if that matters (it should, to you). Also (not answer-specific), you should be replacing `\r\n` instead of just `\n` (from a Windows-standpoint). Also also (not answer specific), you should use prepared statements instead of direct-variable insertion (since you're using mysqli).

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: It looks like you're getting example code from a very old source.  Magic quotes has been removed from PHP a long time ago.  As for how to handle this properly, that's what prepared statements are for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The problem with the apostrophe's:**

You probably use an input like this:

```
<input type='text' value='<?php echo $value;?>'/>
```

The problem is that if the value has an apostrophe this happens:

```
<input type='text' value='Let's play'/>
```

So the value tag is ended because of the apostrophe in your variable.

To fix it simply use htmlspecialchars with ENT_QUOTES:

```
<?php 
 $value = htmlspecialchars("Let's play", ENT_QUOTES);
?>
<input type='text' value='<?php echo $value; ?>'/>
```

That way the apostrophe's get encoded and will be editable in your form

**About the SQL injection:**

Simply use [mysqli's prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and you will be fine. To also keep you safe from XSS, always `htmlspecialchars` user input in HTML output. Even better is to filter the input to only what you need, and save only the filtered input to your database.

Comment: Let me add this. How do I store the apostrophe in the text area into the db using myqsql insert

Comment: You need to use prepared inserts. Or you can use `mysqli_real_escape_string( "let's play" );` (I recommend a prepared statement. You can find everything about that in the link I provided in my awnser)

Comment: If you can give me a little more of a hint on it as I am not completely familiar with the new mysqli yet.

Answer (score -1):

Use `htmlspecialchars()` function when creating the textarea tag:

```
<textarea><?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['Comments'])?></textarea>
```

Comment: Apostrophe's do not matter in textarea fields. And only htmlspecialchars does not encode the apostrophe. You need ENT_QUOTES. By the way: `<?=` is bad practice as it will only work with shorttags enabled `<?php echo` is better.

Comment: John, good points. Just my habits, I guess. Never had a problem.